# Python: Pandas Csv Import, object to numeric

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to import a csv-file with the following content in each line.

```
0;0;0;1;239.57558842082713;0.3690280072634046;[239.6369763080322, 239.5252233951102, 240.21580279356058, 239.86250730788123]

df = pd.read_csv('dataset', sep=';');
```

In the end df.dtypes shows that it is an object, but I want to get the values that I can make for example a line plot.

I tried to convert the object to a string, to remove the '[', ']' and than cast
it to numeric, but I was not successful.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: The column is an `object` type, because a list is an object in python. How do you want to handle the values in the list? Do you want them to be [separate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns), or to remain inside a list in one column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the "list" series as a string, use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), then construct a dataframe and join onto your original dataframe. The resultant series will all have numeric dtypes.

Here's an example:

```
from io import StringIO
from ast import literal_eval

x = StringIO("""0;0;0;1;239.57558842082713;0.3690280072634046;[239.6369763080322, 239.5252233951102, 240.21580279356058, 239.86250730788123]
0;0;0;1;239.57558842082713;0.3690280072634046;[239.6369763080322, 239.5252233951102, 240.21580279356058, 239.86250730788123]""")

df = pd.read_csv(x, header=None, sep=';')

list_cols = pd.DataFrame(df.pop(6).apply(literal_eval).values.tolist()).add_suffix('_L')

df = df.join(list_cols)

print(df)

   0  1  2  3           4         5         0_L         1_L         2_L  \
0  0  0  0  1  239.575588  0.369028  239.636976  239.525223  240.215803   
1  0  0  0  1  239.575588  0.369028  239.636976  239.525223  240.215803   

          3_L  
0  239.862507  
1  239.862507
```

Comment: Hi,
this goes into the desired direction, but my way is still too complicate.
I want to make line graphs containing the 4 values as y-coordinates,
`
list_cols = pd.DataFrame(df.pop(6).apply(literal_eval).values.tolist()).add_suffix('_pixL')
df = df.join(list_cols)
plt.plot([df['0_pixL'],df['1_pixL'],df['2_pixL'],df['3_pixL']])
`

Comment: It seems I've solved your problem: `I tried to convert the object to a string, to remove the '[', ']' and than cast it to numeric, but I was not successful.` If you have a new question, feel free to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).